Does the “It’s now safe to turn off your computer” screen hide a working command prompt underneath?
Is it true that the Windows 95 power-off prompt, "It's now safe to turn off your computer" was just a graphics-mode image over a DOS prompt, and you can type DOS commands at the power-off screen?


Windows 95 didn't really have security local.  User accounts could modify each other's files. Including guests or auto-generated new accounts.

can't see leaving the computer on but able to restart windows would be any different to having it off but able to turn it back on again?

Computers back then seldom had any login sequrity, so if you had physical access to the computer and knew anything about how to do it, it was easy to turn on a computer (or reboot it) and stop the loading of Win95.

On reflection, the security aspect isn’t entirely irrelevant – it might matter for someone assuming that leaving a computer unattended at the “now safe to turn off your computer” screen is exactly as secure as leaving it turned off entirely, where in the latter state it might be protected by a BIOS password. Of course it’s not like a BIOS password can protect against an agent capable of disassembling the computer, but against a relatively unsophisticated evil-maid attack it might be just enough to make a difference.

@AJM I think the downvotes are mostly related to previous versions of the question (look at its edit history).

I am still surprised that so few are willing to withdraw their downvotes now that the question has been edited into shape.

@user3840170 Is there a story about the network ban?

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen None that I was involved in or made aware of. (I could speculate, but would rather not.)

@StephenKitt Looks like you're on course for a very well deserved Lifeboat badge here!

In normal operation, this didn’t happen — you couldn’t enter commands at the shutdown screen. (Pedantically, the computer was still running DOS at this point, but all the user could do was power the system off or reboot it.)
However, if Windows 95 was started by booting into DOS and manually starting WIN, shutting Windows down would exit WIN, leaving the system at an invisible DOS prompt with the “It’s now safe to turn off your computer” screen displayed. Running
mode co80

(or mode mono if your system has a monochrome display adapter) would restore the DOS prompt.
You can see this yourself in action: go to the PCjs Windows 95 emulation, press F8 when the text-mode “Starting Windows 95” message appears, and boot to a DOS prompt (“Command prompt only”). Enter
win

to start Windows, then shut it down. Wait for the “safe” screen to be displayed, then enter
dir

and watch the display get messed up. Enter
mode co80

(or mode mono) and enjoy your DOS prompt again.
If you delete LOGOS.SYS in the WINDOWS directory (the file storing the bitmaps used here), Windows restores text mode itself and displays a message before returning to the DOS prompt:

(Thanks to user3840170 for the reminder.)


If so, it's the most astounding computer vulnerability I've ever even heard of, and I have a masters in digital security.

You must be young.
Historically security wasn't really something vendors of "small" single-user computers worried much about. If you sat in front of a machine, you were it's master and could tell it to do whatever you wanted. This was the case on pretty much all of the historic microcomputers and on early PCs.
Multi-user systems, which attempted to enforce security boundaries between users, did exist, but they were traditionally far more expensive and out of the range of normal folks.
In the late 1990s and into the 2000s, this started to change. Windows NT was designed from the ground up as a multi-user operating system and, if installed on a NTFS partition, could provide workable separation between users.
9x on the other hand lacked serious security features. There were some attempts to lock it down, but they all had holes big enough to drive a truck through because at a basic level the system did not have proper file permissions or memory protection.

A particularly stupid user was playing with it and got himself into a situation I had to come and repair. I removed the DOS prompt option. === DOS access itself was a vulnerability.

So would have been a typical word processor.
Without an enforced system of file permissions, all but the simplest systems are likely to end up with holes big enough to drive a truck through.

While great to put things into context, does it answer the question about being in DOS prompt while showing the turn off graphics screen?


If you sat in front of a machine, you were it's master ...
For a while, of course, this was why PCs often came with a literal keyboard lock on the front panel...


Under normal circumstances, no.  But there are situations where an active command prompt is indeed there.
After displaying the shutdown screen, WIN.COM checks if it has itself as the parent process, and if so, it enters an infinite loop.  Otherwise, WIN.COM will exit.
    ; check if we are our own parent process in the PSP
    mov     ax, cs          ; :0203  8cc8
    cmp     ax, [cs:0x16]   ; :0205  2e3b061600
    jne     should_exit     ; :020a  750a

    ; disable splash screen (?) – <https://archive.ph/2u35H>
    mov     bl, 3           ; :020c  b303
    mov     ax, 0x160e      ; :020e  b80e16
    int     0x2f            ; :0211  cd2f

    ; loop forever
hang:
    nop                     ; :0213  90
    jmp     hang            ; :0214  ebfd

    ; exit to parent process
should_exit:
    pop     ax              ; :0216  58
    mov     ah, 0x4c        ; :0217  b44c
    int     0x21            ; :0219  cd21

The interesting part is under which circumstances will WIN.COM have itself as its own parent process.  One such situation is when it detects it was spawned directly by the DOS kernel, which happens in “Safe mode” boot, or when there is no AUTOEXEC.BAT file to be processed.  The more interesting one is when COMMAND.COM executes the WIN command0 after processing AUTOEXEC.BAT.
In the default configuration, COMMAND.COM will relocate itself to the top of conventional memory during normal boot into VMM32 (i.e. into the protected-mode, GUI component of Windows 9x), but not when booting to a command prompt (e.g. when “Command prompt only” or “Safe mode command prompt only” mode is selected in the F8 menu).  If COMMAND.COM is so relocated, it also exposes an undocumented interrupt call exposing a callback telling COMMAND.COM to unload itself from memory; if this callback is available, WIN.COM will invoke it, and mark itself as its own parent process in the PSP:
    ; invoke COMMAND.COM service
    or      di, 0xffff      ; :147e  83cfff
    mov     ax, 0x5500      ; :1481  b80055
    int     0x2f            ; :1484  cd2f

    ; check if a callback pointer was returned in DS:DI
    test    ax, ax          ; :1486  85c0
    jne     no_unload       ; :1488  7517
    cmp     di, -1          ; :148a  83ffff
    je      no_unload       ; :148d  7412

    ; invoke the callback to unload COMMAND.COM
    lds     di, [di]        ; :148f  c53d
    push    cs              ; :1491  0e
    push    after_unload    ; :1492  689814
    push    ds              ; :1495  1e
    push    di              ; :1496  57
    retf                    ; :1497  cb

    ; become a self-owned process
after_unload:
    push    cs              ; :1498  0e
    pop     ds              ; :1499  1f
    mov     [0x16], ds      ; :149a  8c1e1600
    call    0x180e          ; :149e  e86d03

    ; :14a1 - continue execution
no_unload:

But it turns out the relocation to the top of conventional memory can be controlled independently of the boot mode.  On one hand, putting LoadTop=0 in the [Options] section of MSDOS.SYS will disable COMMAND.COM relocation even in normal boot.  On the other, a SHELL= directive in CONFIG.SYS passing a /T switch to COMMAND.COM will re-enable relocation even when booting to a command prompt.1  Only the former of the two was documented (in MSKB article Q118579), so it can hardly be considered a common configuration.  As such, in practice, Stephen Kitt’s answer describes the behaviour well enough.

0 Which by the way does not necessarily have to be the Windows GUI launcher WIN.COM.  Have you noticed that in “Step-by-step confirmation” mode, after AUTOEXEC.BAT is completely processed, you are asked whether to execute “WIN [Enter=Y,Esc=N]?”?  This is literal.  If a WIN.BAT file is planted in the current directory, that will be executed instead.
1 Some guides to MSDOS.SYS mistakenly identify the top of conventional memory as “the HMA”, which usually refers to addresses FFFF:0010 and above.  (Some others outright claim that COMMAND.COM is loaded into non-conventional memory with this setting enabled.)  Yet in another place on the same site I saw the claim that using the /T switch prevents loading COMMAND.COM outside conventional memory, and also that it “may lock up Windows 9x/ME GUI upon shut down” – which presumably refers to the WIN.COM behaviour explained above.  There is lots of confusion regarding these settings; beware of that.

Do you know more about the relocation that COMMAND.COM can do? Does it relocate an/its existing process?

@ecm Not that much; I mostly relied on black-box testing (change a config file, reboot, run mem /d, rinse, repeat) to establish what I present here. It seems only the permanent shell launched by the kernel as the first process is subject to relocation, but again, I have not investigated that thoroughly. I think I do know how the shell checks the LoadTop= setting, though – a flag returned by interrupt 0x2F/AX=0x1611 in BL reveals it.

I also know how WIN.COM discovers the unloading service – interrupt 0x2F/AX=0x5500 returns a pointer to an address (!) of a far-call routine in DS:DI, but if the shell has not relocated, the value of DI is left unchanged.

Thanks for looking into this! 0x2F/0x5500 returns the general COMMAND.COM interface entry-point, presumably WIN.COM calls that with some other parameters set to invoke the unloading routine.

Ah, 0x5500 returns the interface entry-point in DS:SI, is DS:DI specifically the unload routine?

Not quite – it’s an indirect pointer, to be called as call far [di] (though WIN.COM instead does push/retf for some reason)

Right, I got that, I was curious about the relationship between the unload routine and the DOS 5+ COMMAND.COM interface entry-point.

Do you know why the "hang" loop jumps to a NOP, rather than just having the JMP jump to itself?

@cjs I saw some code elsewhere that apparently replaces the nop with a hlt if the /A switch is passed. It also seems to have other effects I have not studied in detail.
